# Search in specific column in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, search

I have created a `ListView` with three columns and I want to find a value only in specific column (e.g. `PK` column):

```
myListView.Columns.Add("Index");
myListView.Columns.Add("PK");
myListView.Columns.Add("Value");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `myListView.Columns["Index"]` ?

Comment: @Fares this will return `ColumnHeader`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
  if (lvi.SubItems[1].Text=="Text for search")
     MessageBox.Show("!!!!!!!");
```

Comment: **Note:** The first `subItem` in the `ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection` is always the item that owns the `subItems`. Care should be taken when performing operations on `subItems` in the collection to reference index position 1 instead of 0 to make changes to the first `subItem`.